# Is there a LaTeX package to format computer language grammars?

Tags: packages, syntax, grammar

I need to display BNF grammars, but couldn't find any LaTeX package that does this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the [`syntax-mdw`](http://ctan.org/pkg/syntax-mdw) package.

Answer (score 5):

Try [latex-bnf](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-bnf) on ctan.